# Localstorage not storing

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to save the page state when a user looks at an item from search results then goes back to the results.

The surrounding div has an id of `mainContainer` so its basically everything in there that i want to save and then restore.

I'm using native javascript, not jquery.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
// Replace the search results on load.
if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
  if ('myPage' in localStorage && window.location.hash) {
  var el = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
  el.innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('myPage');
    }
}

// Save the search results when leaving the page.
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
  var el = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
    var form = el.innerHTML;
      localStorage.setItem('myPage', form);
    }
};
```

Comment: This will explain why it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/g3j0je2q/ It has nothing to do with localstorage.

Comment: Remove the last enclosing );

Comment: @epascarello I'm not following you

Comment: By the way, are the results shown as HTML content inside `<p>` , `<span>` etc or are they in form elements? Obviously you won't get the values of form elements using `innerHTML`. Which i what i think @epascarello what trying to mention.

Comment: If you're intent is to save the state of the data _presented_ by the html, then you should save the **data** to `localStorage`, not the html.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i can see, your code has a syntax error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    if (('localStorage' in window) && window['localStorage'] !== null) {
     var el = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
     var form = el.innerHTML;
     localStorage.setItem('myPage', form);
    }
 });
//^Here
```

Other than that it seems to work fine: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajqnjdmu/). Just change the content in HTML an run the fiddle again, previous `HTML` will be stored and will be reloaded. (*BTW I removed the hash check for demo purpose*)

Comment: @DarrenSweeney other than that it seems to work fine  http://jsfiddle.net/ajqnjdmu/